# Why do I get "enter parameter value" only when using SELECT AS

Tags: sql, ms-access

This query

```
SELECT P2.ID, P2.Storenum, [Periods_2013-2014].[PeriodDate] AS [OpenFromDate],
  P2.[Open From Day], P2.[Open From Time], P2.[Open To Day], 
  P2.[Open To Time]
FROM [Periods_2013-2014] 
INNER JOIN [tblOpenCloseTimes] AS P2 ON [Periods_2013-2014].[Day]=P2.[Open From Day]
WHERE ((([Periods_2013-2014].Day)=P2.[Open From Day] 
  AND P2.Storenum ="43010605" 
  AND [Periods_2013-2014].Period = "4"))
```

results in an "Enter Parameter Value" with `Query1.PeriodDate` as the requested parameter, whereas if I merely remove the "`AS [OpenFromDate]`" from the first line the query runs perfectly. It does the same if I alias the `[Periods_2013-2014]` table as P1. This wouldn't be a problem except that I need to stack the queries to get the `PeriodDate` field twice. What am I doing wrong?

---

Update: This query

```
SELECT T2.Storenum, T2.[PeriodDate] AS [Open From Date], T2.[Open From Day], 
T2.[Open From Time], T1.[PeriodDate] AS [Open To Date], T2.[Open To Day], 
T2.[Open To Time]
FROM [Periods_2013-2014] AS T1, 
(SELECT P2.Storenum, P1.[PeriodDate],  P2.[Open From Day], P2.[Open From Time], 
P2.[Open To Day], P2.[Open To Time]
FROM [Periods_2013-2014] AS P1 INNER JOIN tblOpenCloseTimes AS P2 
ON P1.[Day]=P2.[Open From Day]
WHERE (((P1.Day)=P2.[Open From Day] 
   AND P2.Storenum ="43010605" 
   AND P1.Period = "4"))
ORDER BY P1.[PeriodDate]) AS T2
WHERE T1.[Day]=T2.[Open To Day]
AND T1.[PeriodDate]>=T2.[PeriodDate] 
AND T1.[PeriodDate] - T2.[PeriodDate] <7
ORDER BY P1.[PeriodDate];
```

works perfectly now that I have deleted the Order By clause from the Property sheet.

Comment: Is this an MS access query ?

Comment: Just a thought, MS Access throws this weird bug sometimes in the SQL editor where it will still see the old syntax even if you have made a change to the SQL and will throw an error message like the one you are seeing. Try creating a new query and pasting the syntax in to that one. I also run into this error message a lot if I have inadvertently misspelled a field name on the table I am querying (or if the field doesn't exist altogether).

Comment: @TomFoale - Just read your comment below about clearing the order by parameter in the properties sheet. This could be the cause of the "weird bug" I described above and now I'll know how to fix it in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Access does not allow you to use field aliases in the query. So, I guess the issue is in your `Where` clause.

Try removing the name:  `P2` and use full table name so that your statement looks like:

```
SELECT [tblOpenCloseTimes].ID, [tblOpenCloseTimes].Storenum, [Periods_2013-2014].[PeriodDate] AS [OpenFromDate],
  [tblOpenCloseTimes].[Open From Day], [tblOpenCloseTimes].[Open From Time], [tblOpenCloseTimes].[Open To Day], 
  [tblOpenCloseTimes].[Open To Time]
FROM [Periods_2013-2014] 
INNER JOIN [tblOpenCloseTimes] ON [Periods_2013-2014].[Day]=[tblOpenCloseTimes].[Open From Day]
WHERE ((([Periods_2013-2014].Day)=[tblOpenCloseTimes].[Open From Day] 
  AND [tblOpenCloseTimes].Storenum ="43010605" 
  AND [Periods_2013-2014].Period = "4"))
```

I was wondering why you used Alias name for one of the tables but not other. Using aliases for columns name is fine. However those alias names should not be used in Where Clause.

Additionally, you may refer below links for more details:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303134
- [Why am I getting “Enter Parameter Value” when running my MS Access query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232639/why-am-i-getting-enter-parameter-value-when-running-my-ms-access-query)

Comment: I replaced all of the aliases with the full table names in square brackets. The same error occurs with the same conditions - only when I use the AS clause

Comment: please use AS clause only for Your Columns. Please try one without using any alias in whole query and then try using Alias only for columns.

Comment: I saved and closed the query, then re-opened it and now it always asks for the parameter value. I copied and pasted your query and that always asks for the parameter value.

Comment: Using the documenter gives:  OrderBy:[Query1].[PeriodDate] OrderByOn: False. The table structure of the Periods_2013-2014 table is ID -Autonumber, Period -Text, Week -Text, Week No - Text, Day -Text, PeriodDate -Date/Time

Comment: So it looks like the AS clause was a red herring

Comment: Yes, I guess, because you are using: " [Periods_2013-2014].[PeriodDate] AS [OpenFromDate]  ". Try using: "  [Periods_2013-2014].PeriodDate AS [OpenFromDate]  ". Remove [] from the column name as u did for: [tblOpenCloseTimes].ID

Comment: I found a Order By query1:PeriodDate in the properties sheet for the query. I deleted that and now the query runs perfectly, with or without the AS clause. Thanks for your help - that had me stumped for a while.

Comment: Glad to know this Tom. So can you confirm if my Query is running as it is. This will be helpful for me too : )