# The parameter inputs show up even when the input boxes are linked

Tags: ms-access, input

I have made a form called "Creating Reports", there are two input boxes, the first input box asks for EmployeeId, and the second one the date. Those inputs are linked with queries and the queries result in different report. Now my problem is that when i enter the buttons the parameter input shows up.
the link to the DB is provided https://1drv.ms/u/s!Alp32kymhCKxv1T4BNSmfLpCbbYl

Comment: Welcome to [so]! You're not really supposed to include links to offsite files for safety reasons (eg, viruses etc), and I'm not going to click that link either! ...but I assume you're referring to Access's **"Enter Parameter Value"** prompts; Most times when they show up unexpectedly it's because of a typo or a missing space, etc, in the field name Like `[Myfield]` that should be `[My field]` or `[MyField` or `[My  Field]`(with 2 spaces) or `[My_Field]` etc...  For a definitive answer you'd need to include screen shots of the issue.  (Also check out how to include an [mcve] as well as [ask].)

Comment: There are other syntax issues that could also cause this to happen. More info from Microsoft on probable causes: [**Why does Access want me to enter a parameter value?**](https://support.office.com/article/why-does-access-want-me-to-enter-a-parameter-value-0e71a1dd-e498-49a1-9e2e-356538d226ff) and similar question & answers on Stack Overflow: [**Why am I getting “Enter Parameter Value” when running my MS Access query?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4232639/8112776) and on SuperUser: [**Access keeps asking to enter parameter value**](https://superuser.com/a/663109/774713).

Answer (score 0):

I took a chance and downloaded file.

Should use combobox for selecting employee.

Should not use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Reports in PrintPreview are not interactive and command buttons will not be available.

I don't use dynamic parameterized queries. Your query references a control named Text37 which does not exist. I don't use macros. If you are going to use any VBA then recommend all code as VBA instead of embedded macros. You have VBA attempting to open report but references query name. Correct VBA syntax for opening report with filter criteria:

```
Private Sub Command16_Click()
DoCmd.OpenReport "Employee's List of samples", acViewReport, , "EmployeeID=" & Me.EMPREPORTQUERY
End Sub
```

Your form appears to be corrupted. I cannot get VBA to work. Had to build a new form.